# Grant on *.* excluding mysql

Tags: mariadb

Is there a way to grant on *.*, excluding mysql.*?  I have a user that I want to have the routine privileges (select, insert, update, delete, create, drop, alter) in all production databases, including any new databases that other users might create.  If I grant on *.*, then the mysql database is included, which effectively makes that user an administrator.  I do not want that user to be an administrator.  I just want that user to be able to manipulate all production databases, without the need to explicitly assign rights for each database.

I am looking for a MariaDB answer.  I will write a script in perl to handle this if I need to, but this seems like something for which MariaDB should have a built-in capability.

In case it matters, I'm running MariaDB v10.2.12 on 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: Can you try `grant ... on *.* to user@host` and then `revoke ... on mysql.* from user@host`? Also see this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98949

Comment: I get, "... no such grant defined for user 'uuu' on host 'hhh'". 

Apparently MariaDB can't revoke a global user privilege for a database. Even if Maria could delete the the user table entry and create db table entries for all databases except mysql, that's not what I want. It would't give privileges for databases created in the future. I want to keep the user table entry but make the mysql database an exception. I suspect it can't be done, but I wanted to throw the question out to the community before I give up on it.  This seems like something a lot of people would have wanted years ago.

Comment: I'd go with the most comforting route - run a Perl script that executes each statement resulting from `SELECT CONCAT("GRANT SELECT ON ",SCHEMA_NAME,".* TO 'user'@'localhost';") FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT LIKE 'mysql'`; every hour or so.

Comment: Thanks.  That looks a lot more compact than what I would have coded.  I did try the grant/revoke sequence suggested in your link, and it did not work for me the way it worked for Infra DBA.

Comment: @zedfoxus - Unless you `GRANT ON mysql.*`, you can't `REVOKE ON mysql.*`.

Comment: This functionality is being currently developed in MariaDB in the scope of https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14443 . There is hope (although no guarantee yet) that it will make it to MariaDB 10.4.